# I can't reach to REPUTATION 1000 , and vote not calculated after 995 but reduced?

Tags: support, reputation

I notice a strange behavior where I can't reach to REPUTATION 1000 , and vote not calculated after 995  but reduced to 993 !

I got this link

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user

after I checked my next privilege as shown below !

[image]

I have already updated my account with my real name and image but I still decreased although I got more voting after 995 !!

Can anyone help me to know what's the main reason for this issue and how I can overcome it ?

**[Update]**

I go to chat room I found out this REPUTATION !!

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Reputation & Moderation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) article in the Help Center, one can read the following:

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day from any combination
>   of the activities below. Bounty awards, **accepted answers**, and
>   association bonuses are not subject to the daily reputation limit.

So yesterday you earned 243 points since you reached the 200 rep limit and had three accepted answers. You can view this in your [reputation tab](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/m-qassas?tab=reputation) on your user profile:

[image]

Accepted answers

[image]

Today you have earned 4 rep points, and the next reputation point you get will make you a 1000 rep user with the privileges that makes you an [established user](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user).

Comment: thank you for your answer , but what about the points after rep limits ? Is it lost ?

Comment: @M.Qassas Yes, they are not added to your reputation. You can only gain 200 reps a day. All above 200 is excluded.

Comment: thank you for your help

Comment: A clarification on "accepted answers are not subject to the daily limit" this only means the 15 reputation points you earn from the answer being accepted. It does **not** mean that an accepted answer that gets 50 upvotes in one day will earn you 500 reputation that day.